# In a REST URL what does the meaning for <pathPram>:<xyz> stands for? And how to process it in sprinboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, path-parameter

For Ex: http://market.com/fruit:banana/price
Here by term one can understand that fruit is a category and banana is one of the values. But I need more understanding on it in order to process it. Also
what if the values are comma sepeareted?
Ex: http://market.com/fruit:banana,mango/price
Can anybody help on this?

Comment: AFAIK neither comma nor colon has a special meaning in URL path parts. So just treat it as a simple String part of the path, then parse it in code later if you need to. Now, if you want to build a nice to use REST API, it's probably better to use a more "standard" type of URL. For example, you could use `/fruit/price?type=banana&type=mango`.

Comment: Colon DO have an special meaning as it's the URL scheme separator and the user:pwd separator. In a URL path is probably the [colon trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Colon_trick)

Comment: @Jorn Thanks for your input. I was given with a task where I need to enahance one of such REST implementations where colons and commas are used in URI. The example URL which I had given is similar to my requirement. So definitely there's a meaning of colon and comma.

Comment: @LMC I specifically said *in path parts*

Answer (score 0):

> In a REST URL what does the meaning for : stands for?

Short version: whatever that specific URI designer wants it to stand for.

---

Longer version: the production rules for path segments in URI are documented at RFC-3986, Appendix A.  The bit we care about in this context is `path-abempty`

```
path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

So as far as general purpose components (browsers, caches, spiders...) colon is just another letter - it doesn't mean anything more or less than the letter "e" does.

As it happens, the same is true of comma (","), which is a sub-delim.

Now, back in the day, Tim Berners-Lee shared an idea he called Matrix URIs.

> Note: relative Matrix URLs are notgenerally implemented so this is just a theoretical discussion. -- TBL

The sample provided looked like:

```
//moremaps.com/map/color;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000
```

With the idea that the key value pairs here represent values in a "sparse matrix" of possibilities.

Part of the legacy of matrix URLs is that we have [URI Templates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570) using [Path Style Parameter Expansion](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.7) -- which is to say that we have a general purpose way of describing a range of identifiers that include key value pairs like

```
/map/color{;keys*}
```

Which would produce the matrix sample if expanded with a suitable map of values.

For your examples, you would get almost the same result with a slightly different spelling

```
/fruit{;list*}/price
```

which would produce your first example if expanded with [banana], and your second example with [banana, mango], *except replacing your colon with a semi-colon.*

Note that this doesn't tell us anything about *meaning*; it's a purely mechanical way to expand/extract information in resource identifiers (provided you are willing to abide the spelling constraints).